# Cannot run scala in intellij but it works in commandline

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jvm

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2016.3.2, with scala plugin installed.

I created a scala project and a file called `Hello.scala` in the `src` directory, with the following contents.

```
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    println("Hello, world.")
}
```

I right clicked on `main` and selected `Run 'Hello'`, then I got an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)
```

But what was interesting was that I could run the scala file in the commandline, just type the following command in the `src` directory in the terminal.

```
scala Hello.scala
```

And the result popped up.

```
Hello, world.
```

What should I do to make it work in intellij?

Comment: Try pressing alt + shift + F10 and select `Hello`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project settings (Alt + Ctrl + Shift + S), Dependencies tab, and check if there's scala-sdk (for example scala-sdk-2.12.1) with scope set to compile (not provided).

If this doesn't work, then check if there are *.class files in output path set in "Paths" tab in project settings.